# What guns could a WerWolf use?

Tags: weapons, mythical-creatures, firearms

Assume these WerWolves are about 8ft tall and are human-level sentient can move their fingers like humans as far as the trigger goes.

Besides larger than normal trigger guards, what other features would guns have to have changed for this specie?

What weapons would reasonably be developed for WerWolves to use?

Comment: Many military firearms have removable trigger guards to allow soldiers to use the weapons in arctic conditions while wearing gloves.

Comment: Werewolves in literature in wolf-form generally use their superior senses in the dark and their cunning to close with and surprise their enemies, and their claws and teeth to inflict damage and pass on the Werewolf Curse. They don't need guns. In human form, they can use guns like everybody else. Are you simply talking about 8-foot wolf-resembling humanoids instead of werewolves? Or are you talking about huge wolves trying to use guns?

Comment: any weapon you want. If they can build them, imagination is their only limit!

Comment: For what purpose? There are many different kinds of guns not so much because people are different but because situations are different

Comment: What's a WerWolf exactly?

Comment: @ash https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werewolf

Comment: @JoeP No that's a Werewolf I know what one of those is what's a WerWolf?

Comment: Same thing, different spelling. Usually used when there are other variants (such as Rat, Boar, Tiger....etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could justify giving the wolves some heavy machine guns, as they would likely be able to carry heavier loads. The high rate of fire could be used to compensate for a lack of visual acuity, since canines have a worse eye for detail than humans do. Having this level of firepower while maintaining above-average mobility would be a game changer combat, particularity in urban or jungle warfare.

Alternatively, you could say that the wolves prefer not to give away their position, maximize the advantages of their night vision, and avoid polluting their air with gun smoke by giving them sub-sonic projectiles like bows or cross bows. Sure, this wouldn't win a full-scale fire-fight, but it might make them victorious in a war of attrition.

In terms of modifications for existing weapons, weapon straps and ammo belts/pouches that will stay with the werewolves while they shape-shift would likely be appreciated. Maybe the smell of gunpowder would be bad enough to warrant different gas vents on weapons. But the most needed modification would definitely be silencer, and not Hollywood silencers. If firing a gun hurts a human shooter's ears, it would be unbearable or even permanently damaging for the sensitive ears of a werewolf.

As a whole, I'm picturing a eight foot tall, seriously hairy Rambo-wolf with a sensible pair of earmuffs. This is your warrior.

[image: A service dog with ballistic eye and ear protection, as well as a fetching vest. ha.]

Answer (score 2):

## Uh.. all of them

Some guns don't even have trigger guards, and the ones that do are easily modified such that you can remove the trigger guards.

We have humans that are 8 feet tall, so literally there is nothing that needs to be changed.